# How to mix tensorflow.js and ml5.js

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Since there is only poseNet model in ml5.js, there is no moveNet model. But I need to use the moveNet model in my application. My requirement is: input the pose parameters generated by the MoveNet model into the neural network trained based on ml5.js for reclassification.After I imported the relevant js file and tested it, I found that there is a certain conflict between tensorflow.js and ml5.js. How should I solve it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <video id="video" autoplay></video>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600px" height="400px"></canvas>
    <button id="bt1" style="position: absolute; left:0px;top: 300px;">AI</button>
    
    <script src="js/ml5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tf.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/tfjs-converter.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/tfjs-backend-webgl.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/pose-detection.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

```
const ipurl = '192.168.30.13'
const video = document.getElementById('video');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvasid');
const bt1 = document.getElementById("bt1")
let detector;
let brain;

const initDetector = async () => {
    console.log('准备加载moveNet...')
    await tf.ready();
    console.log(tf.version)
    const detectorConfig = {
        modelType: poseDetection.movenet.modelType.SINGLEPOSE_LIGHTNING,
        modelUrl: "https://" + ipurl + "/tfjs-posedetection/model.json"
    };

    detector = await poseDetection.createDetector(poseDetection.SupportedModels.MoveNet, detectorConfig);
    console.log('moveNet加载成功！')

};
initDetector();
```

```
function InitBrain() {
    //1.先创建模型，需要模型的输入和输出参数
    const options = {
        inputs: 34,
        outputs: 3,
        task: 'classification',
        debug: true
    }
    brain = ml5.neuralNetwork(options);
    console.log('brain is created.')
    const modelInfo = {
        model: 'model-ytxs/model.json',
        metadata: 'model-ytxs/model_meta.json',
        weights: 'model-ytxs/model.weights.bin'
    }
    brain.load(modelInfo, brainModelLoaded);
}
InitBrain();

function brainModelLoaded(){
    console.log('brain is ready.')
    let inputs = [115.01927971839905, 228.82792949676514, 143.35795938968658, 202.88619995117188, 102.83298697322606, 215.07534980773926, 189.96654748916623, 213.72854709625244, 163.4645640850067, 226.26924514770508, 180.75212240219113, 284.1463804244995, 109.90088731050491, 300.1059293746948, 258.1615090370178, 367.8804397583008, 149.67313408851624, 325.15456676483154, 153.23051214218137, 315.29548168182373, 186.82634234428403, 330.57663440704346, 191.99284911155698, 379.3440580368042, 157.81503319740293, 368.39599609375, 257.3266267776489, 365.07980823516846, 110.35726442933081, 388.5439395904541, 228.77075672149658, 398.75102043151855, 111.84356585144995, 354.69634532928467];
    console.log(inputs)
    brain.classify(inputs, gotResults)
}



function gotResults(error, results) {
    console.log(results)
    //lb1.textContent = results[0].label, results[0].confidence
}
```

here is some errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfLo4.jpg)

When I tried to load ml5.js other position, I found another error。

```
<script src="js/tf.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/tfjs-converter.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/tfjs-backend-webgl.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/pose-detection.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 

<script src="js/ml5.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

here is some errors:
[some errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LEok.jpg)